# Automatically import additional js with a package using systemjs

Tags: angular, three.js, systemjs

I'm using `threejs` in an `Angular 2` app in `Typescript` and I want to use `OrbitControls` which is an example of controls for a 3D scene. It is contained within its own js file and has its own typings. I can't get it to load though... I get the following error :

> THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor

The only way I get it to work is by copying the content or the OrbitControls.js file into the three.js main file. Basically what I would like to do is to find a way that I can configure systemjs so that it loads the OrbitControls.js file as if it were a part of the three.js file, if it's even possible.

Comment: There is a way to declare OrbitControls.js as dependency for three.js in systemjs config file so it will be loaded before three.js - https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#shim-dependencies, no idea if it will work in your case though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your index.html include script tags for both OrbitControls.js and tree.js?

It is possible to update someone's library to work without adding the script tags, and to have it import JS code, but the creator of this particular library decided not to. Try to add the export line for that function in tree.js, but there is no guarantee that the code will work.

I meant to say Try to export that function from OrbitControls and re-export it in tree.js, but there is no guarantee that the code will work.

Comment: No. I thought that was the point of systemjs. To load module when they're needed and not in the index page.

Comment: SystemJS is not for loading arbitrary scripts. It can load modules.

Comment: I guess I'm not completely sure about what a module is. Systemjs loads three.js fine. It even loads three.js when I copy-paste the content or OrbitControls.js inside three.js. I can even use OrbitControls in this case. I simply want to know if I can do without having to do this copy-paste operation.

Comment: A module is a script that export some of its members (functions, classes, vars) using some standards (e.g. ES6, CommonJS, AMD). Whatever is exported can be imported by an external script. 

I never used tree.js, but took a quick look here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/Three.js

As you see, it exports a bunch of scripts,  but OrbitControl.js is not in this list.

Comment: Okay I understand. Then the copy-past thing works because it declares a function :

    `THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement )`

and the three.js exports :

    `module.exports = THREE;`

And it isn't possible to use systemjs to tell it that the module THREE has an additional part in another file ?

Comment: And by "part" I mean function.

Comment: It is possible, but the creator of this library decided not to. Try to add the export line for that function in tree.js, but there is no guarantee that the code will work, because that function may have dependencies on other functions.

Comment: I meant to say Try to export that function from OrbitControls and re-export it in tree.js, but there is no guarantee that the code will work.

Comment: Okay if it is not possible to trick systemjs into thinking it's one file then I guess the answer to my question is "it's not possible". Just update your answer with your last two comments and I'll accept it.